# Ssis tasks slow in azure Integration runtime. Same package is running fast in lower environment with lower configuration

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am facing a challenge where ssis package is running smoothly on lower environment from azure data factory where as it is taking more time in production
Lower environment : 30 minutes
Prod : 2 hrs around
Moving deeper, it is observed that time is consumed moving from one task to another in ssis
Looking at the contents available on google, it seems to be disk/network latency issue from azure
If anyone could help how network issue can be checked from azure monitor.
Please let me know if there is any other thoughts regarding this.

Comment: Are you sure this is not related to the relative load of instance(s) in question? If you suspect its the network, you might want to look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime and run the task directly in your On-Prem env.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: Admin team resolved this issue. We did not get the actual resolution steps.